# Is there a practical way to increase the input impedance of an instrument?

Tags: input-impedance

I have a Lock-In amplifier with an input impedance of 10 MOhm. I am planning on measuring a resistance of many time higher than that.

Is there any practical solution that I can do to increase the input impedance?

Comment: Sure, use an opamp with MOS inputs as a buffer. Do note that above 10 MOhm you have to take all precautions possible to prevent leakage currents because they will disturb your measurement if you don't.

Comment: I hope you're prepared to jump through a lot of hoops. Many things have resistance lower than 10Mohm, including any dust or residue on your PCB.

Comment: Consider using guard rings around the hi-Z input pins.  These are physical PCB traces that encircle the input pins and are set to the same potential with low impedance .  This helps reduce the effects of leakages from the PCB surface.  Look up "op-amp pin guarding" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The classic articles on dealing with high impedance have got to be Bob Pease's "What's All This Stuff" series. Try [this](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/whats-all-femtoampere-stuff-anyhow) and [this](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/whats-all-teflon-stuff-anyhow) for a practical starting point.

And, by the way, measuring resistance does not usually require a high input impedance, since a current-to-voltage converter is norm, and a transimpedance amp is the way it's usually done. Low leakage, yes: low input impedance, no.

Answer (score -6):

I'm sure my answer might not be a good one But you might try replacing some wires with ones that have more resistance.  You might need screwdriver,  wire strippers, soldering iron,  electrical tape, and spare parts either from an instrument with higher impedance or maybe a quiet amp out something.  Make sure you use circuit protection and make sure it doesn't start fire.

Maybe you could use a carbon brush over the wire to increase resistance like a redneck variac. But for instrument.

Comment: Sorry boy, but this answer is realy useless.